# Allow users to withdraw their tokens

Tags: transactions, permissions

In my contract I have an action which is supposed to allow users to collect the tokens they have accumulated. To do this I use:

```
void transfer_token(account_name receiver, asset quantity, std::string memo) {

    action(
            permission_level{_self, N(active)},
            N(eosio.token),
            N(transfer),
            std::make_tuple(_self, receiver, quantity, memo)
    ).send();
}
```

But for this to work I have to use the following command for every user:

```
cleos set account permission <contract> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": <public_key>,"weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor": <user>,"permission":"active"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <contract>
```

My question is:

How can I, using scatter and eosjs, setup the authorization for a user to call an action that transfers tokens from the contract to himself?

edit: I am using scatter on my client, and it has been setup properly, I can use it to transfer tokens to the contract.

edit: Here's the output of using the client to call the action that makes the contract transfer tokens to the user.

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 3090003,
    "name": "unsatisfied_authorization",
    "what": "Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "transaction declares authority '{\"actor\":\"testacccpico\",\"permission\":\"active\"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{\"actor\":\"testacccpico\",\"permission\":\"eosio.code\"}], provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms",
        "file": "authorization_manager.cpp",
        "line_number": 413,
        "method": "check_authorization"
      },
      {
        "message": "pending console output: ",
        "file": "apply_context.cpp",
        "line_number": 61,
        "method": "exec_one"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using scatter and Eosjs in front end? than  I can tell a way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I will be using scatter and Eosjs in the front end.

Comment: did you try `cleos set account permission <account> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<key>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"<contract>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' -p <account>`

Comment: that command just says `transaction declares authority '{"actor":"testacccpus1","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
 `

Comment: maybe `cleos set account permission <account> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<key>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"<contract>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <account>@owner` assuming you have the keys for `<account>@owner` authority in your wallet and your wallet is unlocked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have setup the scatter and eosjs for your front. if not go [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/dapp-development-on-eos-blockchain-using-eosjs-and-scatter-557f1b5b65d0)
After that you need to set permissions, Using two functions like this:

```
async getScatter(nextProps) {
    const scatter = nextProps.scatterObj;
    const { accounts } = await scatter.getIdentity({
      accounts: [config.EOS_CONFIG.network]
    });
    return accounts;
  }

  setNewPermissions = accountName => {
    this.props.eosObj
      .getAccount(accountName)
      .then(account => {
        let newPerms = this.updatePermissions(
          JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(account.permissions))
        );
        console.log(newPerms);

        this.props.eosObj.transaction(tr => {
          for (const perm of newPerms) {
            if (perm.perm_name === "active") {
              tr.updateauth({
                account: accountName,
                permission: perm.perm_name,
                parent: perm.parent,
                auth: perm.required_auth
              });
            }
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
  updatePermissions = permissions => {
    for (let perm of permissions) {
      if (perm.perm_name === "active") {
        let newPerm = {
          permission: {
            actor: config.EOS_CONFIG.contractSender,
            permission: "eosio.code"
          },
          weight: 1
        };
        if (!this.isObjPresentInArray(newPerm, perm.required_auth.accounts))
          perm.required_auth.accounts.push(newPerm);
      }
    }
    return permissions;
  };
```

You also need to import the private key for the account to whom you providing the permission. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried this but it keeps giving me the same error on the jungle testnet

Comment: did you set the permissions correctly. First try to push the transaction using cleos command on jungle test net if it work means something is wrong with permissions or setting scatter.Try to modify my code accordingly to your usecase don't exactly copy it. Because it working fine for my usecase. Give link to your repo So that i can have a look

Comment: Did you use `require_auth(account_name);` in you action. Only two possiblities are there either you set different keys as @confuse00 said or you pushing the action with a account that don't have authority to execute.